# Creating unlimited array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Can anyone help to define unlimited array in C++ to make a sinewave generator, where I can store the value of the sine wave?

```
for (;;)
{
    X[n]= sin(2*PI*f0/fs);
}
```

Comment: Do you have `unlimited` memory to store it?

Comment: Just use good old `std::vector`.

Comment: Nothing in a computer is unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

<s>If you want an "unlimited" (still limited by the available amount of RAM) array you can use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).</s> (See edit below)

However, in your case I would use a large array instead (e.g. up to a million elements or an array size equal to the width of your screen).

**EDIT:** Here is an example

```
  // Declare (and instantiate) a vector
  std::vector<float> vec;

  // Add elements to the vector
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      vec.push_back(i*i);

  // Read and print the elements in the vector
  for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
      std::cout << "vec[" << i << "] = " << vec[i] << '\n';

  // Note:
  std::cout << "Note that a vector is limited to " << vec.max_size() << " elements\n";
```

I still strongly recommend simply declaring a large array because you will probably only need a limited amount of values and you know beforehand how many values you will need (a vector is usually used when you don't know how large an array will be).

Comment: could you help by clarifying how could i define this large array to store the sinusoidal return in it

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it can not be done, you can at least try to iterate through some large constant like `ULONG_MAX`, which is 4294967295.

But first, ask yourself do you have enough memory?